# Hard Drive too slow

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, performance, external-hdd

My computer has been going too slow since I remember, I tried several tips I found on Internet but nothing worked. After spending some time searching about the problem I found that it might be my hard drive so I tried to optimize it with hdparm but it doesn't seem to work because I get some errors whil eithere trying to activate DMA. After running hdparm -tT  on my hard drive this is what I get:

```
Timing cached reads:     2 MB in  2.34 seconds = 874.15 kB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads:   2 MB in  4.15 seconds = 493.51 kB/sec
```

That's really poor performance compated to my external HD:

```
Timing cached reads:   1996 MB in  2.00 seconds = 998.20 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 102 MB in  3.02 seconds =  33.83 MB/sec
```

Is not it?

If someone can please help me to get this computer to run a bit more decent I'd appreciate it.
Here's some info about the hard drive:

```
/dev/sda:
multcount     = 16 (on)
IO_support    =  1 (32-bit)
readonly      =  0 (off)
readahead     = 256 (on)
geometry      = 30401/255/63, sectors = 488397168, start = 0

Model=TOSHIBA MK2565GSX, FwRev=GJ002J, SerialNo=11T3B3E6B
Config={ Fixed }
RawCHS=16383/16/63, TrkSize=0, SectSize=0, ECCbytes=0
BuffType=unknown, BuffSize=8192kB, MaxMultSect=16, MultSect=16
CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=488397168
IORDY=on/off, tPIO={min:120,w/IORDY:120}, tDMA={min:120,rec:120}
PIO modes:  pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
DMA modes:  sdma0 sdma1 sdma2 mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 
UDMA modes: udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 *udma5 
AdvancedPM=yes: unknown setting WriteCache=enabled
Drive conforms to: Unspecified:  ATA/ATAPI-3,4,5,6,7

* signifies the current active mode
```

System specifications

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
07:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
```

Thanks.

Comment: System specifications?  Does your BIOS have an entry of `IDE/ACHI` for the hard drive?  If it does, what is it set to?

Comment: Intel Pentium T4500 Dual Core, 2 GB RAM
The entry in the BIOS is set to ACHI. System specifications attached in the question.